# Reverse number triangle

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a reverse triangle like this:

```
    0123456789
     012345678
      01234567
       0123456
        012345
         01234
          0123
           012
            01
             0
```

I am so close yet so far. This is the code I have for now:

```
    for e in range (10, 0, -1):
for d in range (10-e):
    print (' ', end = ' ')
for d in range (e):
    e = e - 1
    print (e, end = ' ')
print()
```

and the output is:

```
    9876543210
     876543210
      76543210
       6543210
        543210
         43210
          3210
           210
            10
             0
```

Please help :)

Comment: In `for d in range(e)`, `d` is a value going from 0 to `e`. Maybe you could print it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you're over-complicating this:

```
for i in range(10):
     print(' ' * i + ''.join(map(str, range(0, 10 - i))))

0123456789
 012345678
  01234567
   0123456
    012345
     01234
      0123
       012
        01
         0
```

Run a loop from 0 to 9. At each iteration, figure out how many spaces and numbers to print accordingly. As `i` increases, the number of spaces to print increase. Correspondingly, the number of digits to print reduce.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a fun approach.

```
from string import digits

triangle = '\n'.join(digits[:10-i].rjust(10) for i in range(10))

print(triangle)
```

Comment: nice use of `string.digits` (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Simpler way to achieve this will be to create a custom function to:

- Right justify the string based on `n` using `str.format`
- create a string of number in range using `str.join`

Here's a sample function using *generator expression*:

```
def print_triange(n):
    for i in range(n):
        print('{:>{}}'.format(''.join(str(j) for j in range(n-i)), n))
        #        ^ To right justify the string
```

This can also be achieved with `map` as:

```
def print_triange(n):
    for i in range(n):
        print('{:>{}}'.format(''.join(map(str, range(n-i))), n))
```

Sample Run:

```
>>> print_triange(10)
0123456789
 012345678
  01234567
   0123456
    012345
     01234
      0123
       012
        01
         0
```

Comment: *Chapeau* for the originality.

Answer (score 0):

Almost, you have to print `d` instead of `e` in the 6th line:

```
for e in range (10, 0, -1):
    for d in range (10 -e):
        print (' ', end='')
    for d in range (e):
        e = e - 1
        print (d, end='')
    print()
```

And you can use an empty string for `print`'s `end` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner using nested list comprehensions and without using `map` or an `import`:

```
print('\n'.join([''.join([str(j) for j in range(10-i)]).rjust(10,' ') for i in range(10)]))

0123456789
 012345678
  01234567
   0123456
    012345
     01234
      0123
       012
        01
         0
```